# odoo ir.rule xml id not found error

Tags: odoo

openerp.py

```py
    'depends': ['base','hr'],

# always loaded
'data': [
    'security/ir.rule.xml',
    'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    'views/views.xml',
],
```

security/ir.rule.xml

```xml
  <data noupdate="0">
<record id="property_rule_jj_loan_creator" model="ir.rule" forcecreate="True">
    <field name="name">loan creator</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_jj_loan"/>
    <field name="domain_force">[('employee_id.user_id','=',user.id), ('state', '=', 'Draft')]</field>
    <field name="perm_create" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
    <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
    <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

after restart odoo and update the model
the error said:

> raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
>   ParseError: "External ID not found in the system:  model_jj_loan"
>   while parsing /home/addons/jj_loan/security/ir.rule.xml:4, near

I have seen many examples codes are the same as mine, so is there anything I have missed?

thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is about the name of the model : `model_jj_loan` 
the Model jj.loan is not created on you database:

check the name of your model must be like this if not you need to change the name on the xml file :

```
_name = 'jj.loan'
```

if is there with the same name than you need to check if the table is created on your database use pgAdmin and i think you will not found it. if so :
make sure that you import the you module `.py` in the `__init__.py` because odoo will not install a model on the database if it does not exists in `__init__.py` put the model code in the question if you didn't solve the prob

Comment: thank you ,my error caused because my model name is : _name       = 'jj_loan.jj_loan'  ref="model_jj_loan" should be  ref="model_jj_loan_jj_loan"