# odoo ir.actions.server id not found

Tags: odoo-9

I'm new to Odoo. While trying to call a server action from a menuitem it can't find  the model_id.

My view code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="ir.actions.server" id="open_calculator">
            <field name="name">Open Calculator</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="calculator"/>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">
                <!--code-->
            </field>
        </record>

        <!-- Top menu item -->
        <menuitem name="Calculator" id="calculator.menu_root"
                  action="open_calculator"/>
    </data>
</openerp>
```

The error:

raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % (xmlid))
ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: calculator.calculator" while parsing /home/administrador/Escritorio/calculator-test-project/calculator/views/views.xml:4, near

```
        <record model="ir.actions.server" id="open_calculator">
            <field name="name">Open Calculator</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="calculator"/>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
            <field name="state">code</field>
            <field name="code">
                <!--code-->
            </field>
        </record>
```

Model:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields, api, http


class Calculator(models.Model):
    _name = 'calculator'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you got your answer ?

Comment: Hello @KevalMehta, yes! it's a matter of convention, I had to add "model_" as a prefix in my model name. Just as my own answer states. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is a convention you have to follow in model_id's ref attr. You have to add '_model' before your model name:

```
<field name="model_id" ref="model_calculator"/>
```

instead of:

```
<field name="model_id" ref="calculator"/>
```

or it won't work.

Just as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43061771/5750078)

Comment: The same rule applies to fields as well. SOme time ago I wanted to add "vat" field to a different model and got an error because just tried to pull vat instead of partner_id.vat (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911599/odoo-how-to-add-code-field-to-accounting-model)